# Facebook-App without SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl

I'm running a litte webpage with an online game and I want to display the current ranking on the facebook fan page of this game.

So I thought of creating an app, which does nothing else than including the ranking in the app canvas, so that I can use this app on the fan page.

But I have first absolutely no experience with SSL and second do not want to buy a certificate. Is there any possibility of doing what I have in mind without SSL?

It's only importing data into the fan page. There is no interaction with user data, so there is even no necessity for SSL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter an invalid URL under `Secure Canvas URL` field in the application settings section.

The problem is that all users who use Facebook's secure browsing won't be able to see your app since they are redirected automatically to the secure canvas URL.